# How exactly does one store SQL Server on an attached EBS volume? EC2

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an EBS backed EC2 instance, I've heard it's good to store your SQL on another attached EBS volume for

> "sustain many more random IOPS than instance disks (good for typical
>   workloads) and they live independently of your instances. "

How does one do this? Is it just a case of in SQL management studio pointing the MDF storage location for the database on the attached EBS? SO essentially ALL the attached EBS has, is one MDF file? Is there no decrease in speed from this approach?

Comment: Where is that quote from? Perhaps with more context it will make better sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely better to store your SQL Server data and log files on separate volume or you could even consider storing data and log files on separate attached EBS volumes. They indeed "live independently of your instances" if you didn't set DeleteOnTerminate flag. That gives you some freedom configuring storage for your database server, for example:

1. With [provisioned IOPS](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/07/31/announcing-provisioned-iops-for-amazon-ebs/) you could create volumes with guaranteed
   performance.
2. You could increase performance even more using [striped
   volumes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938499.aspx)
3. You could create on-fly snapshots to backup your data -
   be sure to use VSS to guarantee consistency of data files
4. If you run
   out of storage you could attach another volume and create new
   data/log files there
5. etc

Cloud makes lots of new scenarios possible... :)